# How to implement Google map in Xamarin forms

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make xamarin.forms app with google map on page.
Earlier I used  `Device.OpenUri`, but as official documetation says:  "This often navigates out of the application."
My goal is to stay in aplication and make exact the same page like this:
[image]

I can't find any good documentation or step by step tutoriel neighter...

Comment: https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps

Comment: Step by step tutorial
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61982083/how-to-implement-a-single-google-map-in-both-platforms-android-and-ios-using-xam/61982084#61982084]

Answer (score 1):

Did you check [Xamarin Forms Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map)? If you don't like how the default pins look like, you can define a template for them ([check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map#populating-a-map-with-data-using-data-binding)).

In case you already have a link of google maps that you want to show, and you don't want to create it by yourself (solution from above), try with WebView and set URL to the link you have.